# How to edit MSH, PLC, TEX and AIS files

Tags: ais

Might not be the right Site to post this but I wonder if I can edit an older game files that are MSH , TEX , AIS and PLC formats.
I've searched google about those formats but can't actually find solid solutions.
I have this :

[image: Screenshot]

They come from an old game named IGNITION (a.k.a. Bleifuss fun or Fun Tracks) and I love this game so much , it made my childhood.
Now what I want is to somehow edit the files , make the cars have more balanced speeds or add new cars , maps etc.

Comment: Tex are LaTex files that might be easy enough to figure out, not sure about the rest though. Some might be proprietary and/or compiled. You might be going down a *deep* rabbit hole here. I don't find your post too far off topic to be discussed. Certainly these are files related to software programming and you are asking a question about how to modify them. I've seen way "worse" posts.

Comment: @JacobH TEX files here are unlikely to be TeX files.

Comment: @Ivan The rabbit hole goes even deeper...

Comment: You can usw Trid to analyze the files. Maybe it gives you a hint.

Comment: This is not a programming question so it is off-topic here. It may or may not be on-topic at https://tex.stackexchange.com/ or possibly at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.